# Load custom theme in Visual Studio 2013 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2013, themes, custom-theme

I would like to load the Zenburn theme in VS 2013.

I have installed the [Visual Studio 2013 Color Theme Editor](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe) and it comes pre packaged with some default themes, however none of these include the Zenburn theme (which I have grown accustomed to in np++ & webstorm).

I have been able to find the zenburn theme [here](https://studiostyl.es/schemes/zenburn-2012) and it states that it is for vs 2012 & 2013 but the file format is ".vssettings" and is not recognized by the Color Theme Editor plugin.

Is there a way I can load the .vssettings theme into VS 2013 or even a valid Zenburn theme for the Color Theme Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the theme from [studiostyl.es](http://studiostyl.es) just follow the instructions from the [faq](https://studiostyl.es/home/faq) :

> I can't open the .vssettings theme file I downloaded. What do I do
>   with it?
>
> You need to import the settings into Visual Studio. This might look
>   like a lot of work, but it's pretty easy after you do it a couple of
>   times.
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, choose Tools > Import and Export Settings
> 2. Choose Import Selected Environment Settings and select whether you want to
>      back up your existing settings or not
> 3. Click Browse... to choose the file you downloaded.
> 4. You get a choice which settings you want to import - choose all of them since the file only contains color settings and won't touch your other VS settings.
> 5. Click Finish and you'll see the new colors.
>
> Note: if you save the file to My Documents
>   Visual Studio 2010 > Settings, you'll have quick access to choose the settings file in step 3 above.